# Use DatabaseTable Field Description when DataBinding

Tags: c#, database, data-binding

Im using C#, Linq and DataGridView.

I bind my grid like so.

```
var db = new DataClassesDataContext();

var results = db.Results;

.... much later on in the code..

dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
```

It uses the Field names for the columns which saved me heaps of time but is it possible to use the FIELD description so I have better col names for my clients.

What Im doing right now is using  UNDERSCORES in field names

- ID
- USER_NAME
- SUR_NAME

so in the ColumnAdded event I do

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column.HeaderText = e.Column.HeaderText.Replace("_"," ");


    }
```

But its just a work around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that these columns will always represent specific fields in your Database then you could always just set them up directly after you set the datasource for the GridView.

```
DataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Column 1";
DataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Column 2";
DataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Column 3";
DataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Column 4";
```

It's always going to depend on how different the naming convention in your database is compared with how you want to represent each column in the `DataGridView`. It wont always be possible to manipulate them like you have done in your example.

One thing I have noticed that maybe missing. If your planning on allowing the user to edit the data in the DataGridView and committing changes to the `DataContext`, you will need to use a Binding Source between these two objects in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks Derek, the cols will always be the same, and its View only so no changing of data by the User.